# How do we call density/mass function for r.v. that is neither discrete nor continuous?

Tags: probability, terminology

Let a r.v. $X$. Suppose $X$ is not discrete nor continuous. For example, $$\mu_X(dx)=\frac{1}{2}\delta _0(dx)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}m(dx),$$

where $\delta _0$ is the dirac measure at $0$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. So $X$ has neither density nor mass function. How do we call the "mass+density" function of $X$? is there a special name for that?

Comment: I know what $\delta _0(x)$ is supposed to represent, but what is $\delta _0(dx)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just talk about the distribution of X which is a *mix* of a distribution which is absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure (and therefore has a density) and a discrete distribution (with a mass function).

Comment: In your example you could write it as $\mu_X (A) = \frac{1}{2} 1_{0}(A) +  \frac{1}{2} \int_A \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x $ for Borel-sets $A$.
($1_0$ is the Indicator funtion of {$0$} and $\phi(x)$ the probability density function of a standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A probability density function, such as the standard normal density $\phi(x)$, has a natural interpretation when used in an integral. This can be translated into a measure-theoretic basis. So too in, a more generalised sense, does the interpretation of a Dirac delta function in an integral.

So if you are prepared to call $\delta_0(x)$ a generalised probability density function, then you can also call $\frac12 \delta_0(x) +\frac12 \phi(x)$ a *generalised probability density function*.  Some would even drop the *generalised*.

Comment: That's a pity... So, at the end, the term "density", works also for non-continuous r.v... (up to generalized...)

Comment: @Walace - this does not work so simply for the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution), which has a continuous cumulative distribution function but not an absolutely continuous cumulative distribution function